# What kind of cool stuff can I do with PHP's streams?

Tags: php, stream

It seems that PHP's [streams](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) aren't used much, but they appear to be very powerful. Does anyone have an example of implementing a stream to do something that would be clunky otherwise?

I don't mean doing stuff like `file_get_contents('http://google.com');`, I mean implementing your own streams.

Comment: Whatever you do, *don't cross them!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of examples that spring immediately to mind are:

- Accessing files with an [**Amazon S3**](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4144-PHP-Stream-wrapper-to-get-and-send-files-to-Amazon-S3.html) wrapper.
- Interacting with [**MongoDB's GridFS**](http://github.com/crodas/MongoFS).
- Talking to [**Microsoft Excel**](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1919-PHP-Stream-wrapper-to-read-and-write-MS-Excel-files.html).
- Getting [**blobs from Windows Azure**](http://phpazure.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Blob%20storage%20stream%20wrapper).